# I can import my custom framework but I can't use a class in it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I built a swift framework and integrated it into my project.
It was automatically added to the Linked Frameworks and Binaries and I also added it to the Embedded Binaries.
I can call #import myFramework from anywhere in my project files, but when I try to use a class from myFramework xcode says: Use of unresolved identifier ...

1. I returned to myFramework files to verify the classes are public and they were.
2. I verified that myFramework path (the actual framework file) is in Framework Search Path.
3. I started a new swift project and integrated myFramework into it the same way. That worked! I could import the myFramework and use its classes with no problem.

What can be misconfigured in my original project that I can't use myFramework from it?

Comment: Did you specify `public` keyword ? Bu default `internal` is used

Comment: Yes. But I don't think the problem is in myFramework (see no.3 above)

Comment: Just select your target and under General settings tab -> check the 'Linked frameworks and libraries' section your custom framework should appear there, if not then try adding it by clicking the + symbol.

Comment: I did. It is equivalent to selecting the framework item in the Project Navigator and than check my main target in the 'Target Membership' at the File inspector window. That didn't help. But as I mentioned it did work in another fresh project that I started just to test this framework. I guess it is a configuration that I miss in my original project  :|